# right adjusting content of contenteditable div after appending image

Tags: javascript, css, contenteditable

I can append image to contenteditable div, but when the content is full and I am appending the image to the end, the content is not moving to left after appending.

```html
<div id="msg" contenteditable="true" class="disabled" maxlength="300" style="width:20%"></div>
<img id="img" src="http://localhost/cc/public/img/smileys/face with hand over mouth.png">
<button value="Send" onclick="sendMessage1()" id="sndmsg">Send</button>
```

```js
function sendMessage1(){
        var elem = document.getElementById('msg');
        var img = document.getElementById('img');
        var clone = img.cloneNode(true);
        clone.removeAttribute('id');
        elem.appendChild(clone);
    }
```

```css
#msg img {
    height: 20px;
    margin: 3px 2px;
}
#msg {
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    width: 25%;
    height: 27px;
}
[contenteditable="true"] {
    white-space: pre;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div id="msg" contenteditable="true" class="disabled" maxlength="300" style="width:20%"></div>
<img id="img" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196">
<button value="Send" onclick="sendMessage1()" id="sndmsg">Send</button>
```

See the below image,

[image]